# Installing Ubuntu on a SecureBoot machine with no existing OS

Tags: grub2, acer, secure-boot

I was given some bad(malicious) advice, and my entire OS was deleted. I had Ubuntu before, fully replacing the Windows 8 that came with my Acer Aspire 1 laptop. I tried reinstalling Ubuntu from a flash drive, but the HDD security wouldn't let me boot after the restart at the end of installation. In grub, pretty much every command tells me Secure Boot won't allow it. Is there anything I can do? Ubuntu preview loads just fine, and I'm trying to install from there, but I figure Secure Boot will block me again after restart.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the BIOS menu by pressing DELETE or F2 or whatever the key combination is for your laptop. There should be an option to disable Secure Boot. Look in the UEFI section its probably in there.

Comment: With secure boot on, Ubuntu will install in secure boot mode and should work. But better to not use secure boot at least for now until all the issues are resolved.